# Avoiding global dependency on Core Data (or similar persistence frameworks)

Tags: ios, core-data, architecture, dependencies, dependency-management

Data persistence frameworks like Core Data can greatly speed up app development, by reducing the amount of code required to support data storage.

One major disadvantage of adoption such a framework however, is the introduction of what inevitably becomes a global and cross-cutting dependency right through the codebase.

Dependency on such frameworks come in several forms, including, but not limited to:

1. Referencing or subclassing key API classes - so for Core Data, that would be things like `NSManagedObjectContext` and `NSManagedObject` etc.
2. Behavioural dependence - the framework provides some less obvious implicit functionality, which the app somehow depends on fundamentally to work. In the case of Core Data, this might be automatic management of inverse relationships.
3. Feature dependence - the framework provides features which other options lack. In the case of Core Data, this might be multi-level undo.

With this mind, my questions are:

1. When working on greenfield code, what strategies are best used to avoid introducing a major cross cutting dependency like this?
2. What techniques are best used when there is an existing dependency which needs to be broken? Say for example Apple deprecated Core Data, and it therefore needed to be replaced, on iOS-only app needs to become a cross-platform app.

Answer (score 1):

Isolate your domain model from your persistence model.  Isolate your persistence layer from your domain layer, using DALs or Repository patterns to keep it isolated.  It's expensive, often tedious, mapping domain models to persistent entities, and destroys a lot of the value of automatic domain->relational mapping tools.

You really are going to have to make a hard decision here, do you want independence, if so, you will have to architecturally isolate, which will be expensive.  It will make other things easier though, testing an isolated domain model is a beautiful thing.  Testing models where behavior is hidden in frameworks is an exercise in misery.